# How to transfer files between Android and Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.10, android, mtp

I have an Android phone (Samsung Galaxy S3) and I wish to take the music files I have off of it and store them on my laptop which is running Ubuntu 12.10. Upon connecting my phone to my computer I can see the phone but if I try to open it to view it's contents I receive an error saying that my device was not mounted. Is there any quick fix which will allow me to take music and other files from my phone to store them on my computer?

Answer (score 37):

I gave up trying to get MTP support on Linux for the moment.

Here is the solution I use now:

1. On your Android device, install [FTP Server](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=FTP%20Server&fdid=be.ppareit.swiftp_free) (it's free and open source)
2. On your Ubuntu computer, install Filezilla
3. Make sure both your computer and your Android device are connected to the same WiFi network
4. On Android, launch FTP Server, and check "Running". It will provide you an IP and a port.
5. In Filezilla, connect to yoru Android device using these information, and ftp/ftp as login/password (you can change this in FTP Server if you want)
6. You can then navigate into your device from your Ubuntu computer! I usually use this to transfer music on my Android Samsung Galaxy S3 (I put it in /storage/extSdCard/ directory)

Comment: Nice solution. I wish I knew about FTP server earlier. Now I use almost exclusively [Bitorrent Sync](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync/) to do that. It works quite well on linux and is *ideal* for very large files.

Comment: -1 completely insecure - [the app doesn't support encryption at all](https://github.com/ppareit/swiftp/issues/16). I haven't tried it, but it looks like [Primitve FTPd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.primftpd) supports SSL.

Comment: I gave up on MTP because the transfer rate is so unreasonably slow, thanks Microsoft.

Comment: @l0b0 -1 seems harsh. This is a perfectly valid solution on a secure private Wifi network. (+1)

Comment: Installed ES File Explorer & Used Remote Management to Copy files to device via FTP.

Comment: Can confirm this works for 16.04, though one file at a time somehow.

Answer (score 23):

This android version uses MTP (Multimedia Transfer Protocol) and PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol). Ubuntu doesn't come with MTP support installed. Install gMTP and you can transfer the files.

Comment: Sweet, and that seems like exactly what I was looking for especially beacuse I didnt have this issue when in the PTP usb mode

Comment: gMTP may work for other phones similar but the S3 was unable to connect even after using `Run $ mtp-detect`

Comment: Just tried this myself with a Samsung Galaxy S2 to no avail. Kept having to force quit. In the end I transferred the desired items to memory card and plugged that into the computers card reader. Bit long winded but it works.

Comment: gMTP is ok with nexus4

Comment: What about cloud storage?  Dropbox is probably the most popular, Ubuntu One also has an android app; personally, I use SpiderOak (but I heard that its android app is not very good - I didn't test it myself, though, and generally I found SpiderOak superior to Dropbox).

Comment: gMTP also worked for me with a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 - but only after updating libmtp to the latest version per these instructions: http://www.humans-enabled.com/2011/12/how-to-fix-samsung-galaxy-nexus-mtp.html

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks - Here is the command: 
sudo aptitude install mtp-tools mtpfs gmtp

Comment: Working with Nexus 5

Comment: `gMTP` also works in Ubuntu 14.04 with Lenovo s650 phone with a small action: I had to upgrade some libraries from `ppa:langdalepl/gvfs-mtp` and now I can access and download phone content in gMTP.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with an HTC One. Never detects the device. Running `mtp-detect` gives me the error "PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface".

Comment: Correction. gMTP does technically work, but is so horribly slow as to be unusable. It takes about a minute for every connect/browse/add/delete action to run. Why in the world did Android abandon the USB storage device interface that was blazing fast and "just worked"?

Comment: @Cerin I believe it is because directly mounting the filesystem can cause apps to crash or unmount if any files are in use. Still, it seems like that would be a much better trade-off in my opinion.

Comment: @Cerin I can confirm this. HTC One is a pain to use with Ubuntu.