# How to transfer files from Samsung Galaxy?

Tags: android, samsung, ftp, transfer

:)

I have a Samsung Galaxy that doesn't communicate very easily with any computer... 
I want to be able to transfer files (now I email them one by one..., nope don't have cardreader either)
I found an answer here regarding a similar issue, 
( [How to transfer files between Android and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240846/how-to-transfer-files-between-android-and-ubuntu) )
suggesting to download the app FTP. It says it is free, however I find it as a paypal service. Unfortunately I am not able to install/use paypal...
Any details I've missed?

Thanks for the help!

/isabelle

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the mobile phone into mass storage mode, it is then recognized like a USB stick.
This website describe show it's done:
http://www.recovery-android.com/connect-samsung-to-computer.html